# Storing an array in javascript file and using it in another file

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have researched this problem and have not found a simple solution, or it has not been broken down into something I can understand. This should be extremely simple but it is not.

I need to store data (array) in one file (file1)

```
const myArray= new Array['data0', 'data1', 'data2'];
module.exports = { myArray};
```

the inside of the second file I try to import it and call it like this (file2)

```
import myArray from './file1';
console.log myarray[0, 1, 2]
```

Comment: You export the array as an object with a property in it called "myArray".  Also you're exporting it via old-school `module.exports` and then trying to import it as an ES2015 module.

Comment: Also that `new Array[]` syntax is incorrect; all you need is the array initializer.

Comment: I hear what you are saying. I do not know how to fix that. it seems so simple but I am at my wits end with it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll be honest with you, I can't think of a usecase in which you would need to export/import a simple string array.  Exporting an object (containing an array, perhaps) has a bit more utility.  But the following should work.

```js
// file1.mjs
const myArray = ['data0', 'data1', 'data2'];
export default myArray;
```

```js
// file2.mjs
import myArray from './file1.mjs';
console.log('myArray =>', myArray);
```

Comment: this is just throwing a TypeError: not a constructor error

Comment: I don't know how you got a TypeError but there was a ReferenceError (whoops!).  Try again.  I don't know what JS engine you're running this in, but in Node, you may have to update your `package.json` and run your app like the following `node --experimental-modules file2.mjs`. 
https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#packages_determining_module_system

Comment: I am running in node. Thank you. I was able to solve this with your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Export

```js
export const myArray = ['data0', 'data1', 'data2'];
```

Import

```js
import { myArray } from './file1';
```

Comment: same issue. I get a "not a constructor" error

Comment: const myArray= new Array['data0', 'data1', 'data2']; it wrong you cant create array that way.
const myArray = ['data0', 'data1', 'data2']; like this or
const myArray = new Array('data0', 'data1', 'data2'); like this

Comment: but then I added a console.log

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did that worked for me (this is in node, not sure about browser)

file2.js:

```
const arr = ["a", "b", "c"];
export {arr};
```

file1.js:

```
import {arr} from "./file2.js"
console.log(arr);
```

outputs: ['a','b','c']

need to have "type":"module" set in package.json

I was confused at first as well on why the other posts weren't working, but when I changed it to the full file name it worked.